# Can someone please explain the following definition of $\ln(e^z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I noticed someone do this from one of the questions is asked on here i had:

$$e^z = -0.5$$

$$e^z = 0.5e^{i\pi}$$

which magically became:

$$z = \ln\left(\frac12\right) + iπ + 2ikπ$$

does this mean that if i have:

$$e^z = -r = re^{i\pi} = \ln(r) + iπ + 2ikπ$$

Thanks for any help you can offer me, i have really been strugling with this,

edit:

Oh my bad i meant to write:

$$e^z = -r = re^{i\pi} = \ln|r| + iπ + 2ikπ$$

Comment: $x+iy = |x+iy|e^{i\text{arg}(x+iy)}$. Now use the fact that $\ln$ is additive. Note that $arg(x+iy) = Arg(x+iy)+2\pi k$ is the multivalued argument of $x+iy$. In your example, $r$ would be positive, as it represents the norm of a complex number.

Comment: For the reasons given above, we do not call $\log(z)$ a "function" since it is not well defined (i.e., multivalued).  As JessicaK points out, we can avoid that issue by referring to Log$(z)$ which is indeed a function with a single answer for each $z$.

Comment: In the last display, you have set a quantity equal to its own logarithm, which is not what you wnated to do. You have to rewrite that string of equations as two (strings of) equations, one for $e^z$, another for $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r \in R$ and let $z \in C$, where $e^{z}=-r$. Since $e^{i\pi}=-1$ and $e^{2i\pi}=1$, it follows that $e^{z}=e^{z}\cdot (1)^k=e^z\cdot (e^{2i\pi})^k=e^{z}\cdot e^{2ki\pi}=r\cdot(-1)=r\cdot e^{i\pi}$ where $k\in Z$. Now taking the logarithm of both sides of the equation $e^{z} \cdot e^{2ki\pi}=r\cdot e^{i\pi}$, we have that $ln(e^{z} \cdot e^{2ki\pi})=ln(r\cdot e^{i\pi})$. So $z+2ki\pi =ln(r)+i\pi$ and thus $z=ln(r)+i\pi-2ki\pi$. Since k is an arbitrary integer, we can rewrite this expression as $z=ln(r)+i\pi+2ki\pi$. Hope this helps.

Comment: omg, this makes so much sense!, thank a ton, even i get it now! 
$e^z$ = $e^z*e^{2ki\pi}$ = $r*e^{i\pi}$ thinking of it this way HELPED ME SO MUCH.

Comment: am i right in saying that $e^z = 1$ is $e^z*e^{2ki\pi} = 1*e^{2ki\pi}$ and therefore $z = ln(1) = 0$ with the $2ki\pi$ having cancelled out??

Comment: The one thing wrong that equality is that your assuming that both sides are dependent on k. So you would have to using two different integers. For example $e^z\cdot e^{4i\pi}=1\cdot e^{34i\pi}$. So $e^z\cdot e^{2ni\pi}=1\cdot e^{2ki\pi}$ becomes $z=2(k-n)i\pi =2ji\pi $ for some integer j.